# Custom Android theme doesn't apply to dynamically created views

Tags: android

I'm creating `RadioButton`s programmatically in Android based on dynamic content. To simulate that, I've created a `makeRadioButton(string)` method. When I add a view to a layout dynamically, it does not take the custom theme I defined in the Android Manifest.

Here's a code snippet:

```
public void makeRadioButton(String name) {
    RadioButton rbTmp = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
    rbTmp.setText(name);
    rbTmp.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
    rbTmp.setPadding(50, 50, 50, 50);
    getApplicationContext().setTheme(R.style.CustomAppTheme);
    rgRadioGroup.addView(rbTmp);
}
```

And here's a screen shot:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The first `RadioButton` was added to the layout with the GUI. The second was added dynamically with the code above. They're both part of the same `RadioGroup` so when one is checked, the other is unchecked, as expected.

I can't seem to find anything that will allow me to set the theme to a single view programmatically, and I would expect my dynamically added view to take the app's theme set in the Android Manifest.

Comment: Try use whatever Activity the RadioButtons are part of for Context, not the Application context.